# Can't run command in vbscript when passing variables with white spaces

Tags: vbscript, command

I'm trying to use obj.Run to compress a file with 7zip but I can´t compress files whose paths have white spaces although I am escaping them. 
The path of the file that will be zipped can have white spaces, and it will receive the name of the file zip and the path of the input files as variables, previously defined.

> Syntax:  `<7z.exe> a -tzip -p<password> <destination zip file> <input file>`

```
Set WshShell=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
```

This is the instruction I´m trying to use to compress the file.

```
WshShell.Run "CMD /C """& path7zip &""" a -tzip -pVIRUS D:\folder\"&processName&".zip "&""""&processPath&"""",0,True
```

To debug, I have added an instruction to echo the same string that is passed to run command, and if I copy and paste it back to command prompt it compress the file without issues.

```
Wscript.Echo "CMD /C """& path7zip &""" a -tzip -pVIRUS D:\folder\"&processName&".zip "&""""&processPath&""""
```

This is and example of the line it displays to command prompt:

```
"C:\Archivos de programa\7-zip\7z.exe" a -tzip -pVIRUS D:\folder\imreallybad.exe.zip "D:\Documents and Settings\Administrador\Datos de programa\imreallybad.exe"
```

Comment: try without the `CMD /C ` parameters, only keep 7z.exe related.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article with canned zip and unzip functions, perhaps the syntax will help you:

http://www.naterice.com/articles/38